# How to get the index of the element by class that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<button class="remove" value="1" />
<button class="remove" value="2" />
<button class="remove" value="3" />
```

```js
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

It is always alerting `0`. If the user clicked the `button` that has a value of `2`, it must alert `1` but in my code it alerts `0`.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cp2rfhue/. Note however that your HTML is invalid as the `button` elements should really have closing tags like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cp2rfhue/1/

Comment: Given that your buttons have the class "remove", I'm guessing that they are not siblings as shown in the question, but are actually contained within table rows or some other elements, where clicking the button is supposed to remove its parent item? That would explain the alert always showing 0. @RoryMcCrossan - maybe OP is using xhtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on what you want to finally achieve and assuming that:

```
<button class="remove" value="34" data-myval="a"/>
<button class="remove" value="33" data-myval="b"/>
<button class="remove" value="32" data-myval="c"/>
```

if you want to get the value of 'value':

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

if you want to get the index of what was clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

if you want to get a custom value:

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
    alert($(this).data('myval'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan), you have to improve the [html button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

```js
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="remove" value="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="remove" value="2">Button 2</button>
<button class="remove" value="3">Button 3</button>
```